# Understanding Azure Bot - why can't I get attached file data

Tags: azure, bots, microsoft-teams, attachment

I am new to using azure bot service

I have a bot that is used inside Microsoft Teams

I use this bot to send and receive messages inside Microsoft teams

When the user tags the bot and sends a text message I get it in the activity response

But when the user tags the bot and sends an image attached to the message I do not get any information about that image

```
"attachments" : [ {
    "contentType" : "text/html",
    "content" : "<div><div><span itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.skype.com/Mention\" itemid=\"0\">BotName12</span>&nbsp;Msg&nbsp;</div>\n</div>"
  } ],
```

above is what I get ,
I expect to get also "contentUrl","content" and "thumbnailUrl"

Is it related to permissions ? If so, where do I define it,
On the Bot, or on the Application related to it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please refer below document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: Thanks, If I am not mistaken, this is for sending attachments as the bot, I am looking for the other way around, to get the URL (contentURL) of attachment that the user uploaded (and tagged the bot) . I need to get the URL and download the file

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the procedure and the image is being uploaded perfectly and the text message also sent successfully in MS Teams.

Follow the instructions mentioned below screen.

[image]

[image]

Click on **Channels** to choose MS Teams

[image]

Select **Microsoft Teams** and attach the created bot to **Teams Channel**. After channel attachment, click on **open in teams**

[image]

The above procedure may not be the code part, but the procedure to create the bot and attach to teams perfectly.

The required contentType and other attachments information can be retrieved by setting name property and contentUrl property to the URL related to the media file. content, contentType, contentUrl, name, thumbnailUrl are the properties need to be given. Then the Activity object which is responsible for your message will specify the Attachment object within your attachments array.

For example, consider the following code for the single image upload.

```
POST https://your-website/apis/v3/conversations/abcd1234/activities/5d5cdc723
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
```

Here comes, the JSON response for the content uploaded as an attachment

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "234567",
        "name": "sender's name"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "user234",
        "name": "conversation's name"
   },
   "recipient": {
        "id": "bot234",
        "name": "recipient's name"
    },
    "text": "Here's a picture of the duck I was telling you about.",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "image/jpg",
            "contentUrl": "image URL"
        }
    ],
    "replyToId": "234"
}
```

To implement different types of media cards if needed [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). We can include AudioCards as well.

Comment: Thank you for the example , But as I said, I don't need the bot to send attachments. I need, when a user (not the bot) uploads an image to the conversion, to be notified about that. Currently in the notification I get I only get the "text" that the user entered but not the images he attached

Comment: Check out the updated answer of code block and the updated attachment for the implementation.